# @typescript-eslint/naming-convention: How to mix error and warn rules?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am trying to set up naming conventions for my project.

I have some variables in `snake_case` that I would like ESLint to warn me about such as:

```
const { order_id } = req.params;
```

I removed `typescript-eslint/camelcase` as it is deprecated and trying to set up `naming-convention` and added a new `error` rule for boolean.

```
 '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': [
          'error',
          {
            selector: 'variable',
            types: ['boolean'],
            format: ['PascalCase'],
            prefix: ['is', 'should', 'has', 'can', 'did', 'will'],
          },
        ],
```

How can I add a warning for `snake_case` variables?

Answer (score 9):

If you want ESLint to warn you about variable names which are not in camelCase it is as simple as:

```
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
  "warn",
  {
    selector: "variable",
    format: ["camelCase"]
  },
],
```

Respective warning shown in VS Code:

[image]

Comment: But would that work with the current rule I have for Boolean ?

Comment: No I mean, I want to apply the two rules. One with `error` severity and the other one with `warn`

Comment: My understanding of the [documentation example](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md#selector-options) is that you can write multiple rules and separate them into severity levels. But since it states that using option  "types"  "will require that you lint with type information", I believe it will only work if you explicitly write types in your variables.

Comment: Does anyone know what "linting with type information" means? I cannot get the OP's boolean example to work.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to get a similar setup working with mixing `warn` and `error` level configurations (e.g. an error-level rule that class names are PascalCased and a warn-level rule that variable names are camelCase). I tried writing two rules in the eslint file, one at `warn` and one at `error`, but found that the second rule in the eslint file was the only one that was respected, whichever it was.

I ended up setting everything to `warn`, which was not my ideal solution but is better than nothing.